# How to predict if my network card is compatible with certain network card

Tags: computer-vision, industrial

I have Marvell Yukon 88E8072 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller installed on my laptop. I want to buy industrial camera that will be compatible with my laptop, soo that I am able to capture images.

How can I predict compatiblity of camera with my network card? I don't want to buy camera for 2k and then I would see that something doesn't work :D

I want to buy camera like the ones from Alied VIsion https://www.alliedvision.com

Here we can also see (Page 1) that there are some Intels cards listed that are compatible...

Tnx for any information and advices!!

Comment: if you don't know such things, are you sure you need such an expensive camera? be careful not to waste your money...

Comment: I'm just student in new job, so this is my first task here...ordering proper equipement for some MV application. I know that I must have GigE network card that supports jumbo packages. Also I have some experiance with image processing but not much experiance with hardware selection. Thats the reason I'm asking for help...

Comment: most machine vision tasks can be solved with cameras cheaper than 2000 dollars. I assume you are not talking about rupees or something :)

Comment: Maybe I was overreacted about the price yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any decent gigabit ethernet card will do.

The adapter should ideally support jumbo frames.

http://www.visiononline.org/vision-standards-details.cfm?id=168&type=5

http://www.stemmer-imaging.co.uk/en/knowledge-base/gige-vision-driver-network-switches-cards-and-cables/

Comment: Thanks thats what I wanted to hear from You :) My adapter is GigE and it supports jumpo packages. It is also not so old laptop that adapter is  in...